# MongoDB command call in gitbash showing error

Tags: mongodb, git-bash

Can anyone please explain the meaning of this error message displayed in gitbash when I try `mongo` command? `mongoDB` was installed successfully on the system. I ran mongod in a separate gitbash window to run the executable to begin the server:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-06-16T16:34:41.678+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2018-06-16T16:34:41.678+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: check if mongodb process is running. What was the last message you get on console when you started the server?

Comment: last lines in console were - exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2018-06-16T04:04:08.038-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-06-16T04:04:08.038-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: your server is not started. Make sure the directory C:\data\db is present and then start the mongod.exe

Comment: created the directory manually and now it's working, thanks a lot!